# transferring the onCreate code to onResume

Tags: android, onresume

Whenever I delete an item from the recycler view, it doesn't refresh the list, I have to open the app again to refresh

I believe the problem is onResume because whenever I go back it doesn't refresh

my onCreate code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.barakah.camel.R.layout.browse_fragment_layout);
        setActionBar();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(com.barakah.camel.R.id.my_recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        data = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");

        if (data.size() < 1) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Oops! No Record Found.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    alert.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alert = builder.create(); // create one
            alert.show();
        } else {
            adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(data, SearchResultActivity.this);
            adapter.setClickListner(SearchResultActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

here what I put in my onResume

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(data, SearchResultActivity.this);
    adapter.setClickListner(SearchResultActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my onResume method?

Comment: whenever a change occurs in the adapter you need to refresh it by calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged () after you remove

Comment: i tried to do it in both onCreate and onResume, it didn't work

Comment: @AryamSaleh hi there did you find solution for this?

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged () ` after the delete has been successful. The best place to call this is the callback of the delete logic.